# google script - creating a list of values to be inserted into an email

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm new to Google Script and Javascript in general.  But I'm trying to email a list of file names pulled from a spreadsheet.  The names are in a column in my sheet, and I created a variable called "newfiles", which pulls out just the values that I need.  So far so good.

```html
function sendUpdate()
{
 
  //set up variables
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("finishedfiles");
  var range = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
 
    for (n = 0; n < range.length; n++)
      {
      var newfiles = range[n][1];
      }
```

The problem is that the script sends out an email for each value in the range.

```html
var startRow = 2;
  
for (var i = 0; i < range.length; i++)
if (startRow + i , 5 != '')
      {
       MailApp.sendEmail
       {to: "me@gmail.com", 
       subject: "list of files", 
       htmlBody: "Here's your list:<br>" + newfiles +
       "<br>This message was sent automatically."});
       }
```

I would like to send only one email, so I need to combine the values in my variable into one text string that can be inserted into my message.

I feel like this is a n00b question, but I can not for the life of me figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you want one big email you mustn't call MailApp for every file name in the range.

```
function sendUpdate() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp
      .getActiveSpreadsheet()
      .getSheetByName("finishedfiles");

  var range = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  var filenames = range
    .map(function(row) {return row[1];}) // Extract the filenames column
    .join("<br>");                       // Combine them all into a string

  MailApp.sendEmail(
    {to: "me@gmail.com", 
     subject: "list of files", 
     htmlBody: "Here's your list:<br>" + filenames +
     "<br>This message was sent automatically."});
}
```

What does `if (startRow + i , 5 != '')` do? Doesn't it always evaluate to `true`?

Comment: nice `map` method usage!

Comment: Thanks Max, I find that adopting functional programming techniques makes GAS coding so much easier.

Comment: The "if" function is left over from when I was trying to do two things at once - mail the list, and also mark the last column "finished" so I wouldn't accidentally send any duplicate emails.  I see now that's why I was getting multiple emails, because it would get the first value, send the email, mark the column, and then repeat for every value.
 
Your solution worked great, so I've separated the two.  Now it
1a. picks out the column and builds a list
1b. mails the list

I'm still having trouble getting it to loop through and mark only certain cells finished, tho. Any tips on loops?